# No visible @interface for 'Fraction' declares the selector 'add:'

Tags: objective-c, interface, identifier

I'm learning Objective-c programming and there are two errors I cannot solve. Could you tell me what's wrong?

```
#import "Fraction.h"
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction *bFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [aFraction setTo: 1 over: 4];
    [bFraction setTo: 1 over: 2];
    [aFraction print];
    NSLog (@"+");
    [bFraction print];
    NSLog (@"=");
    [aFraction add: bFraction]; /*error 1: No visible @interface for 'Fraction' declares the    selector 'add:'*/
    [aFraction reduce];
    [aFraction print]; }
return 0; }


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Fraction : NSObject
@property int numerator, denominator;
-(void) print;
-(void) setTo: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(double) convertToNum;
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼-(void) add: (Fraction *) f; 
-(void) reduce; /*error 2: Expected identifier or '(' */
@end
```

Comment: Is there any other code you're including in these files? Perhaps #defines or something?

Comment: yes, the Fraction.m hasn't been posted for there are no errors. Need I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Grab [TextWrangler from App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12)
2. Open the offending .h file
3. Select <kbd>Text -> Zap Gremlins...</kbd>
4. Check "Substitute with •"
5. [ZAP!]

...

```
 -(double) convertToNum;
 ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••-(void) add: (Fraction *) f; 
 -(void) reduce; /*error 2: Expected identifier or '(' */
```

...

There's your problem right there!

---

Phillip is most likely correct.  And I bet it is a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>.   Try this:

Go to the end of the line that declares the `reduce:` method, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

The cursor will likely jump back to the beginning of the line that declares the `add:`.   This happens if you happen to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> at the end of a line.

To fix, go to the beginning of the line with `reduce:`, hit <kbd>backspace</kbd>, then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

---

Example:

```
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼-(void) add: (Fraction *) f; 
-(void) reduce; <*** cursor here, hit ctrl-a
```

After pressing ctrl-a, the cursor will be at the beginning of the line declaring `add:`.   That means you have a bad return character at the end of the `add:` line.

Check the line before and after, too.   Philip said he saw funky characters at the beginning of the `add:` line.   Also, Xcode does have a "show hidden characters" feature.  That might help but, in my experience, the bad newlines are invisible.

Comment: Yes, I hit the keys and the cursor jump to the beginning. And I hit "backspace" and then "return" as what you said. But the errors remain..thank you both, bbum and David.

Comment: Are you sure you got rid of the incorrect character?  When it jumps to the beginning of the line, you want to move the cursor down one line, backspace, and return.

Comment: I took a try just now. when I hit ctrl+a ,the cursor jumped not to the beginning of the add: line but the one of the reduce: line..and the problem remains..

Comment: Nuts -- different problem.  Still an invisible character as Phillip indicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and the TextWrangler you recommend which is cool :),  bbum. There is really a line of "•••••••" before the add:.  When I delete them, the errors remain. I guess there are maybe something wrong with my operation elsewhere and It's better for me to retype the entire code from the beginning. I'l try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some strange character or characters at the beginning of the `-(void) add: (Fraction *) f;` line.  If I paste your interface section into Xcode, I get the same error as you do in the .h file.  If I delete that line and re-type it, the error goes away.

Comment: I copy the code from the book 《Programming in Objective-C 4th Edition》by Stephen G. Kochan.

Comment: Right...I'm not saying there's anything wrong with the code, just that you may have hit some accidental bad key combination while typing it.

Comment: thanks, Mills. Maybe there are something wrong with my copying process.